# Complex number de moivre theorem

Tags: complex-numbers

[Here's image and Exercise 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD4ry.png)
Hi folks, I would like to ask some explanation of 3rd exercise. To be precise how we get $4^{31}(\cos \frac{7\pi}{6}+i\sin \frac{7\pi}{6})$?

Please could you explain it step by step, Yes I know how de Moivre theorem works but I'm confused with this number $41$ transforming to $31$
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on typesetting math on this site.

Comment: The changing of $41$ to $31$ is a typo. It should be $41$.

Comment: @MPW okay if so how we got $4^{31}(\cos \frac{7\pi}{6}+i\sin \frac{7\pi}{6})$?

Comment: See my answer posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the 41 to 31 business is a typo. It should be 41.

Next, the notation is misleading. They mean that $(41\times\frac{11}{6})\pi = \frac{451}{6}\pi=(74+\frac{7}{6})\pi$. The idea is to leave an even integer out front, since it will produce a whole multiple of $2\pi$.

Then they reduce this to an angle between $0$ and $2\pi$, which would be $\frac{7}{6}\pi$.

Comment: Wow that seems clear now, Thank you so much I was trying understand it for one hour but you make it clear in one minute!

Comment: @BakhodirIbragimov : You should practice reducing like this. Make up several fractions with denominator 2,3,4, or 6, and large random numerator (several hundreds). Then try to rewrite each as (even integer) + (fraction between 0 and 2).